# meaning of "consists of doing all that one ought to want to do and not being forced to do what one ought not want to do"

Tags: meaning

what's the meaning of this phrase

"liberty consists of doing all that one ought to want to do and not being forced to do what one ought not want to do"

Comment: It reminds me of the line from the Anglican prayer book which says something to the effect: 'We have erred and strayed from thy ways like lost sheep...We have left undone those things which we ought  to have done, and done those things which we ought not to have done'.

Answer (score 1):

Liberty is doing everything you should want to do and not being forced to do things you shouldn't want to do.

Things you ought to want to do might include:
Prosper, procreate...

Things you ought not want to do:
Live in captivity, work for no compensation...

I thought "ought to" might be throwing you off.

Comment: And the author and work?

Answer (score 0):

Taking the sentence apart into some smaller parts should help:

> all that one ought to want to do

The writer assumes there are things that you should be wanting to do. He makes a clear distinction in this way from "the thing one wants to do".

> All that one want to do
>   All that one ought to want to do

I would guess that the writer is of the opinion that the things you ought to want to do are things that you want to do *because there is a moral base for it*. Depending on the underlying moral definitions, this could defined in different ways: if I am an altruist, I *should* want to help people; if I am a hedonist, I *should* want to do things that give me pleasure.

In contrast, there are the things that one should *not* want to do: If I am an altruist I *should* not want to take selfish actions or willingly hurt the interests of another.

The writer describes *liberty* as a situation in which one is free to do the things that one believes one *should* want to do, while at the same time, one is not force to do the things that one should not want to do.

The sentence would have been easier to understand is it was written as:

> liberty consists of doing all what one wants not being forced to do what one does not want.

However, the writer does not want to describe liberty in this way. If it is about doing what one wants to do, and not having to do what one doesn't want, there is no moral underpinning for one's actions.

It would mean that liberty consists of me saying "no, I will not work, because I don't want to".
I could then argue that a society in which I am expected to work and contribute to the society does not have liberty.

However, in a society that depends on individuals contributions, I am expected to *want* to work to contribute to society.
I am *not* expected to accept, for instance, that I would have to give up my privacy for that society.

So I *ought* to want to work, and I *ought not to* want to give up my privacy.

According to the writer, liberty consists of enabling me to work and not forcing me to give up my privacy. (This is of course a simplification by example - the writer mentions *all* I ought to want to do, and *all* I ought not to want to do).